# Apply config to all library modules in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following structure for an android project:

```
repo
-app
-lib1
-lib2
```

Within each of the libraries I have the following code to configure the output pom and aar files:

```
android.libraryVariants.configureEach { variant ->
    variant.outputs.configureEach {
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            outputFileName = "${project.name}-${project.versionName}.aar"
        } else {
            outputFileName = "${project.name}-${project.versionName}-${variant.buildType.name}.aar"
        }
    }
}

project.getGradle().getTaskGraph().whenReady {
    tasks.withType(GenerateMavenPom.class).tap {
        configureEach {
            destination = file("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.name}-${project.versionName}.pom")
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = project.group
                artifactId = project.name
                version = project.versionName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I don't love duplicating identical code like this across multiple gradle files. I would ideally like this config to get applied to all library projects (ie to lib1 and lib2, but not to app as that would cause errors). I have tried adding the above to the allprojects section of the root build.gradle, but that understandably errors. Is there some way to do what I am trying to do or do I just need to live with a bit of code duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live with a bit of code duplication? Never! This looks like a good job for a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/8.7-rc-2/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins).

To write one:

1. Add a `buildSrc` folder with a `build.gradle` file of its own. This is automatically applied as an "included build" of your project.
2. The `build.gradle` file needs to apply the Groovy Gradle plugin which compiles your plugin for use by project build scripts:

```
// buildSrc/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

3. Inside the folder `buildSrc/main/groovy` you can write your plugin in a file eg `myFirstPlugin.gradle`.
4. Then you can add your shared config into the file. You'll need to apply the Android library plugin there, or any other external plugin you are going to configure in yours. Any such external plugins should be included in your base project `build.gradle` file, typically using the `apply false` notation<sup>1</sup> so they are on the plugin's classpath.

```
// buildSrc/main/groovy/myFirstPlugin.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android.libraryVariants.configureEach { variant ->
    // variant configuration
}

// any other shared configuration
```

5. Finally, apply your plugin in whichever projects need it, using the filename of the plugin. (You don't need to re-apply external plugins applied in your plugin.):

```
plugins {
    id 'myFirstPlugin'
}
```

<sup>1</sup>Alternatively the external plugin JAR can be added to the implementation configuration of the `buildSrc` project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by moving the common code out to a separate gradle file `libs.gradle`, then using

```
apply from: '../libs.gradle'
```

at the end of each of my library gradle files. This seems to work like copy and pasting the code in to the file, meaning it inherits the file's plugins, variables, and scope.

Comment: Looks good. However maybe worth noting the recommended approach now is to use the `plugins` block where possible, which requires a little more configuration. See discussion at eg https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations